# Iniciar el servicio de laravel automáticamente

Tags: laravel-5, laravel

Es posible ejecutar la instrucción **php artisan serve** automáticamente cuando se inicie el servidor, ya sea desde localhost cuando yo abro el control panel de xampp o desde un servidor real.

Comment: Lo mejor según las buenas prácticas de Laravel sería utilizar Homestead para ambiente de desarrollo y bueno, en un servidor "real" no se necesita dicho comando.

Comment: Recuerda que es un servicio para pruebas o desarrollo y no debes usarlo en ambientes productivos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si es un servidor Linux, podrías agregar al final del archivo `/etc/rc.local` lo siguiente:

```
php artisan serve
```

Con eso se ejecutaría al inicio.